# Recorrer DataGridView en C#

Tags: c#

Buen día solicitando de su apoyo para recorrer un `DataGridView` en **C#** y obtener el valor de cada `ID` en una columna es decir , si tengo un numero **`N`** de ID's dentro del `DataGrid` , al dar doble click sobre cada uno de ellos me mande un `MessageBox` en el que me indique el número de `ID` que seleccioné.

Intente hacerlo con el siguiente código pero solo obtuve el valor del último `ID`

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvInfoNomina.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  dgc = dgvInfoNomina.Rows[i].Cells[0];
  IdNomina = (dgc.Value.ToString());
}
MessageBox.Show("El Id es" + IdNomina);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo encontre, es tan simple como las siguientes líneas:

```
string cadena="";

cadena=datagridview1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();

MessageBox.Show(cadena);
```

Hay que aclarar que en el evento multiple seleccion debemos dejarle el valor en false.

Answer (score 3):

Si tu gridview solo permite seleccionar una fila a la vez no necesitas iterar sobre la colección de filas, solo utiliza:

```
var IdNomina = dgvInfoNomina.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].ToString();
```

Para acceder al id seleccionado, en caso de tener multiseleccion debes iterar sobre la coleccion de filas seleccionadas:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvInfoNomina.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
            {
                var IdNomina = dgvInfoNomina.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].ToString();
                MessageBox.Show("El Id es" + IdNomina);
            }
```

En este caso mantén el `MessageBox.Show` dentro del ciclo `for` o solo te mostrara el ultimo id accedido por el ciclo.

Comment: En la opcion uno me marca este error: El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la colección.
Nombre del parámetro: index

Comment: La opción dos me muestra los id uno tras otro, la idea es que me muestre el valor al dar doble clic sobre el.

Comment: Eel evento lo debes colocar en el doble clic en cualquiera de las opciones y el error que te muestra debes validar que la coleccion de SelectedRows contenga elementos. Saludos